# Inno Setup task bar icon

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, inno-setup, cx-freeze

I used Inno Setup to pack my application, and I gave it an Icon for Quickstart and Desktop:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}..."
Name: "{group}..."
Name: "{commondesktop}..."
Name: "{userappdata}...."
```

This works, but now I got the request to not have the taskbar icon in Windows 7 to show a standard `.exe` icon:

[image]

What am I missing here; searching for taskbar icon doesn't help me?

Comment: I used cx_freeze on Python to build the application. Is it there that it has to be included then?

Comment: Taking back, sorry... No, it can be the shortcut icon...

Comment: I did not understand do you already have custom taskbar icon and want to *remove* it, or do you want to *add* missing custom taskbar icon? Windows 7 shows in taskbar the icon that resides inside EXE-file, and Inno setup has nothing to do with internal EXE resources, it is your linker's job. So, if you *do want* custom taskbar icon - you should link your EXE-file with that icon resource. If you *do not want* custom taskbar icon - link your EXE-file without an icon resorce and use your icon only in shortcuts that must have it (the latter task is done with Inno setup).

Comment: @mas, it shows the icon of the shortcut, which is by default an exe icon. You can try it by yourself if you change the icon of the shortcut.

Comment: @TLama I have tried it - none of us is fully correct - for me it shows shortcut icon when application *is not running*, and its internal icon when it *is running*. So changing shortcut icon will not be enough.

Comment: @Dualinity In your case I think you should configure cx-freeze properly about the icon resource to use (or, if is not possible, you can try to use binary resource editor on your EXE). Shortcut will take EXE-file's icon as default.

Comment: @mas, then we observe different behavior. If I change a shortcut icon of an icon on desktop and execute the target from that shortcut, the new icon is shown on my taskbar. Then if I pin such running application to taskbar it still shows the icon of the shortcut. And that's what I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon inside the exe file is set by cx_Freeze when you freeze it. You can set the `icon` parameter to Executable:

```
executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base, icon="my_icon.ico")]
```

[Docs here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#cx-freeze-executable).

I think the shortcut icon is set by Inno setup, although it may copy the exe icon by default.

EDIT: It turns out it was also necessary to set the window icon within the program - in Tkinter, this is done like this:

```
root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico')
```

Comment: On Windows XP, it shows it now in the folder correctly, but still not on the task bar... I am unable to test on win7 at the moment, but is there no platform independent solution (given that this solves it for win7)?

Comment: I think in XP, you need to set the window icon from inside your code. If you're using Qt, you can probably set it in Qt designer.

Comment: Unfortunately in this project, not using Qt, but tkinter. Once I can confirm it works in Win7, I will mark as answered! Thanks for answering either way.

Comment: From other questions, it looks like you can call the `tk.iconbitmap()` method with the path to a .ico file to set the window icon.

Comment: Yea, this did it: `root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico')` (though cx_freeze apparently does not see it as a dependency)

Comment: Yep, cx_Freeze can only detect libraries automatically. You should be able to put the icon in `include_files` to have cx_Freeze copy it.